# Position image into background

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, positioning, z-index

I'm working on a website for a girlfriend of mine.
But I'm stuck positioning a the logo.

Here is the website I'm talking about:

> http://xntriek-test.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

I tried using z-indexes but don't work. I also tried setting an background image for the body.
But then I'm to limited with sizing the image.
I'm using Twitter bootstrap to put this thing together.

At the moment this is the class I'm using for the logo:

```
.logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  height: 45%;
  width: 30%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

At the moment I'm positioning the image in a span along side the main content.
But because I'm using position: absolute this wouldn't make a difference were I put it.

If any body has any ideas how I could solve this, maybe a different approach then I'm doing right now. Any help welcome!

Comment: Where do you want to position the logo?

Comment: Seems to be moving around fine for me when I inspect it. On another note, are you sure you want to size the logo by percentages like that? It seems to skew in all sorts of weird shapes as I scale the page.

Comment: Using `<img src="#">` for logo doesn't seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your CSS along the following:

```
<div class="span6 offset3" style="position: relative; z-index: 1">
```

`z-index` affects positioned elements, so just add `position: relative` to your span of interest.

I would create a special class "z-wrap" and modify the style sheet.

```
<div class="span6 offset3 z-wrap">
```

In CSS style sheet:

```
.z-wrap {position: relative; z-index: 1}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index

**Note** You may have to adjust the value of z-index depending on any z-index value you may have set in the logo container.

Answer (score 0):

First you are distorting the logo with your css, if you want your image to be responsive position it in an responsive element, position this absolut and let the image adjust it's size.

```
#logoContainer {
 position:absolute;
 top:25px;
 left:25px;
 width:30%;
 z-index:-1;
}     

img.logo{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
}
```

your html should look something like this:

```
<div id="logoContainer">
 <img src="yoursrc/logo.gif" alt="The Logo" class="logo" />
</div>
```

Put this right after the opening of your body tag and not in some other elements.
By putting it in other elements the logo inherits their z-index and you can only influence it's z-positioning inside the parent but not on the overall page.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember when using the z-index attribute :

Only the elements placed **using their "position" attribute** (relative, absolute or fixed), can be affected by the "z-index".

So if you want to fix your issue, either put your logo as a background image, either use **position** in the CSS of the content.